# Can controller get textfields from view in rails app where fields are generated from loop:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

my view is basically a loop creating a lot of fields, I want to store all field values to database when the button **Store Scores** is pressed, how can I access each fields score and store it in the right *level.score* attribute from the controller's *save_scores* method?:

```
<p>Found : <%= @levels.length%> levels.</p>
<h2>Score board:</h2>
<% @levels.each do |level|%>
    <%= form_for(level) do |f| %>
        <% if level.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(level.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this level from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
                <% level.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_field :score %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <!--<%= f.submit %>    -->
        </div>
    <% end %>

<%end%>
<%= button_to "Store Scores",
              :action => 'save_scores',
              :id =>@game
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book Rails Recipe (2012), there is one recipe I think suit your purpose.

**Recipe 36 Create one form for many models**

```
Class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

Class Ingredient < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Add a Recipe

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %> <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :instructions %> <%= f.text_area :instructions %>

  <%= f.fields_for(:ingredients) do |ingredients_form| %> 
    <%= ingredients_form.label :name %> 
    <%= ingredients_form.text_field :name %> 
    <%= ingredients_form.label :quantity %> 
    <%= ingredients_form.text_field :quantity %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `accept_nested_attributes_for' for #<Class:0x007f8173934940>

Comment: with an 's' after 'accept' the for gets created but the scores does not get stored when i submit, in the example above, that corresponds to the ingridients not being stored, do i need attr_accessible or something?

Comment: The issue is further discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186061/failing-to-store-nested-attributes-values-for-models-in-rails-rails-recipes-36?noredirect=1#comment26649124_18186061

Comment: So it turns out to be the permit function's problem. However as for this one form for many models problem, I think I have given the reasonable answer. If you think so too, please up vote it. Thanks~